# c# shorten data annotation using resources file

Tags: c#, data-annotations

I have all these models that use data annotations to validate and display nice messages to my API/Interfaces

For example:

```
public class ConversionViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources)), StringLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLengthErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))] public string Name { get; set; }
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessageResourceName = "RangeErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))] public int FeedId { get; set; }
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessageResourceName = "RangeErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))] public int FieldId { get; set; }
    public Operator Operator { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources)), StringLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLengthErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))] public string Expression { get; set; }
}
```

Now there is tooooooo much going on there.
I would like it if I could shorten the annotations down a bit.
All of my annotations throughout the project look **exactly** like the ones in here. Is there a way of shortening them (and still use my resources file) so it looks like this:

```
public class ConversionViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(100)] public string Name { get; set; }
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)] public int FeedId { get; set; }
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue)] public int FieldId { get; set; }
    public Operator Operator { get; set; }
    [Required, StringLength(100)] public string Expression { get; set; }
}
```

Maybe I could write a custom attribute that always uses my resources file?

Comment: Have you considered using Fluent Validations instead to clean up your view models?  https://fluentvalidation.net/aspnet

Comment: Can you use the resources file with that?

Comment: Sure, you use them normally in code

Answer (score 0):

Probably OT but...

May be formatting the code would achieve a similar result, personally I prefer each attribute on it's own line, I find it so much easier to read.

```
public class ConversionViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLengthErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessageResourceName = "RangeErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    public int FeedId { get; set; }

    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessageResourceName = "RangeErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    public int FieldId { get; set; }

    public Operator Operator { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessageResourceName = "StringLengthErrorMessage", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    public string Expression { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: personally, I don't like doing that :)